# How to using json fields inside where statement in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel, sequel-gem

I have a table `transactions`

```
 id             | bigint                      | NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('transactions_id_seq'::regclass)
 transaction_id | bigint                      | NOT NULL
 middleware_id  | text                        | 
 opname         | optype                      | NOT NULL
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone | NOT NULL
 finished_at    | timestamp without time zone |
 request        | jsonb                       | NOT NULL
 answer         | jsonb                       |
```

Where request can contains data like:
`{ plugin_id: string, item_src_id: string, item_dst_id: string, payload: {}}`
or
`{ plugin_id: string, item_id: string, payload: {}}`

I can select transaction list for some `item_id` like that with pure SQL:

```
SELECT id, request
  FROM transactions
  WHERE 'BEX456'
    IN (request->>'item_id', request->>'item_src_id', request->>'item_dst_id')
```

But, when I use that request with Sequel, it warns me about

> SEQUEL DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling a dataset filtering method with
>   multiple arguments or an array where the first argument/element is a
>   string is deprecated and will be removed in Sequel 5.

For that request:

```
$db[:transactions].
  where("? IN (request->>'item_id', request->>'item_src_id', request->>'item_dst_id')", data[:item_id]).all
```

I can use `Sequel.lit` for that string inside the where op, but my question is - **can I use native Sequel operators for selecting json inside field**?

This works for me:

```
$db[:transactions].where(
  data[:item_id] => [
    Sequel.lit("request->>'item_id'"),
    Sequel.lit("request->>'item_dst_id'"),
    Sequel.lit("request->>'item_src_id'") ] ).first
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postgres' JSON operators are available in the [`pg_json_ops` extension](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_json_ops_rb.html).

Load it beforehand:

```
Sequel.extension :pg_json_ops
```

And then, in your particular case:

```
# request ->> 'item_id'
:request.pg_jsonb.get_text('item_id') # WITH core extensions
Sequel.pg_jsonb_op(:request).get_text('item_id') # or WITHOUT
```

You have the power of Ruby too:

```
["item_id", "item_dst_id", "item_src_id"].map { |key| :request.pg_jsonb.get_text(key) }
```